# AJAX post request error

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

```html
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
try{
 xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("POST",'https://138.19.129.1:8010/hUa7ZhdMv',false);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
 xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify("fname=Henry&lname=Ford"));
}
catch(e){
 alert(e.message);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the error **failed to execute 'send' on 'xmlhttprequest' failed to load**
But this url can be accessed from outside with python POST. And yes i tried

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files

import json
import requests
url = 'https://138.19.129.1:8010/Ugxh4AaABAQ/'
payload = {"echo" : '<b>EXAMPLE</b>'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(payload), headers = headers, verify=False)
print(r)`
```

Added python code

What could be the issue here?
Thank you.

Comment: Where's the Python part of your problem?

Comment: @bad_keypoints added python code

Comment: I found out that the AJAX call does a OPTIONS method call first. not the POST. so I went ahead and received that from a function in the server. But I still get the error even after sending a response of 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's something to do with the server side you are trying to post. Did you check it?